# What does “Do Uncle Sam” mean?

Tags: phrases

I came across the phrase “*He got a kick out of doing Uncle Sam*,” in the following sentence of Jeffery Archer’s novel, “Not a penny more, Not a penny less.”

“It amused him (Harvey Metcalfe, a billionaire who climbed up from a NYSE messengerboy) to do a little business in Europe at the same time, giving him the opportunity to make some more money for his Swiss bank account in Zurich. He did not need a Swiss account, but somehow *he got a kick out of doing Uncle Sam*.”

What does “*Do Uncle Sam"* mean? I don’t find the head of “Do Uncle Sam” in Google Search, or on Ngram.

Does “*got a kick out of doing Uncle Sam*” mean “excited in doing American dream business”?

Comment: ***doing*** here seems to imply *cheating*. Then the rest of it makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've got to admit I'm not 100% sure on this one, but I think Archer is using the verb [to do](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/do+away+with) in TheFreeDictionary's sense 12 *(slang) To cheat; swindle*. And [Uncle Sam](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Uncle+Sam) (US) is slang for America (the nation, government, people,  military, etc.)

By stashing the money in a Swiss bank account (commonly understood to be *untraceable by tax authorities*), Metcalfe is cheating the American government of its rightful share (of tax which should be paid).

To [get a kick out of something/doing something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+a+kick+out+of) is another slang/informal usage meaning *to enjoy doing something very much*. The implication being that even though Metcalfe is a billionaire (who shouldn't actually *need* to chisel the government out of a bit of tax), he just likes doing it for "fun".

Comment: @FumbleFingers.I didn’t know the usage of ‘do’ as 'cheat.’as a slang.  Can I say ‘He did me, and took $10,000 away from me.’?

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: You certainly could - we'll have you passing for a native English speaker in no time at this rate! There's a fairly well-known variant [did me up like a kipper](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=%22did+me+up+like+a+kipper%22&pbx=1&oq=%22did+me+up+like+a+kipper%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=566457l573103l2l573655l25l23l2l0l0l1l190l2653l10.13l25l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=4c26890357e371b1&biw=1262&bih=764), which may just mean *treated me badly/humiliated me* rather than *cheated me out of money/valuables*, but I don't know the origin of that.

Comment: ...also note that *"I'll do you!"* doesn't mean *"I'll cheat you!"* - it means *"I will beat you up"* (as in "fight you and win decisively, leaving you badly injured").

Comment: I was unfamiliar with the usage, ‘have sb. doing’, though I see ‘have stg. done,’ pretty often. Your comment had me relearn usage pattern of ‘have’.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: You'll have your work cut out learning every usage of the verb *to have* - there are a lot of idiomatic contexts for that one. Note that as far as I know, there aren't really many contexts where you can say you'll *have sb. done [by sb. else]*. But as you say, it's quite common to *have stg. done [by sb.]* **And** (you'll hate this!) *"I'll have you!"* is pretty much synonymous with *"I'll do you!"* in previous comment. You must sometimes wish the English (language) had never been born! :)